# Function Returned Data Type

Tags: powershell

I've written a function that will create an Active Directory user based on the supplied parameters. The user creates fine; however the problem that I'm running into is the returned data from the function. I'm merely looking to return a boolean response based on if the user was created or not. Instead, it's passing back an array.

A sample of the function:

```
    Function CreateUser () {
      param([string]$ParentDN, 
            [string]$FirstName,
            [string]$LastName,
            [string]$Username,
            [string]$EmailAddress,
            [string]$Password);

      Try {
        $UserOU = [ADSI] "LDAP://$LDAPServer/$ParentDN";
        $NewUser = $UserOU.Create("user","cn=$Username");
        $NewUser.Put("sAMAccountName","$Username");
        $NewUser.Put("givenName","$FirstName");
        $NewUser.Put("sn","$LastName");
        $NewUser.Put("UserPrincipalName","$Username@$NetworkFQDN");
        $NewUser.Put("mail","$EmailAddress");
        $NewUser.SetInfo();

        $NewUser.SetPassword("$Password");
        $NewUser.SetInfo();

        $flag = $NewUser.userAccountControl.Value -bxor 65536; #Password Never Expires flag
        $NewUser.userAccountControl = $flag;
        $NewUser.InvokeSet("AccountDisabled","False")  #Enables Account
        $NewUser.SetInfo();

        return $true;
      }
      Catch {
        return $false;
      }
    }
```

And I'm calling it using the following syntax:

```
 $CreateUserResults = CreateUser -FirstName $User_FirstName -LastName $User_LastName -EmailAddress $User_EmailAddress -ParentDN $User_ParentOU -Password $User_Password -Username $User_SamAccountName
```

Any advise or direction would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not where I can test, but I suspect those `setinfo()` methods are returning data that needs to be redirected to `$null` to prevent it from being returned by the function.

Comment: Try `$null = $NewUser.SetInfo();` or `$NewUser.SetInfo() | Out-Null` (might need to do it for other calls like SetPassword as well).  That should indeed do the trick.